# Using mtime or mmin to find files in last day

Tags: linux, command-line, find, date, command

I have this find command that compresses png files.

```
find /path/to/folder -mtime -1 -mtime +0 -exec pngquant --ext .png -v --force 256 {} \;
```

I've also tried using `mmin` like so

```
find /path/to/folder -mmin -1440 -mmin +0 -exec pngquant --ext .png -v --force 256 {} \;
```

The -1 and +0 in `-mtime -1 -mtime +0` are variable, and can sometimes be -5 and +4, or so have you.

This command never returns results. When I remove the `mtime +0` or `mmin +0` it brings the expected results, but I need to be able to control the value so I can pass values above 0 such as -5 and +4.

How should I alter my find command to target files in a 24 hour period?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in variable you could do as following.

```
find /path/to/src -type f -mmin -$((60 * $hourP)) -mmin +$((60*$hourN))  -exec pngquant --ext .png -v --force 256 {} \;
```

also better to use `+` in place of `\;` for `exec` termination operator to accomplish like `pngquant a b c` rather than `pngquant ;pngquant b; pngquant c`

For an example:

```
hourP=5
hourN=4
find /path/to/src -type f -mmin -$((60 * $hourP)) -mmin +$((60*$hourN))  -exec pngquant --ext .png -v --force 256 '{}' +
```

Comment: This is a syntax error at `*`. Is this suppose to be pseudo code?